# Django don't save the image from the form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, image-uploading

I try to do dashboard with data uploading. I don't get any error when I upload it, and the new Product is saved, but there is no image.
Below is the code.
How to fix it?

models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    rating = RatingField(range=5) # 5 possible rating values, 1-5
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name=u'Photo', upload_to="product_pic", blank=True)
```

form:

```
    class Addproduct(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Product
```

.html

```
    <form action="/addproduct/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <div class="inputBloc">
            <p>
                {{form.name.errors}}
                <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product name:</label>
                {{ form.name }}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{form.slug.errors}}
                <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Slug:</label>
                {{ form.slug }}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{form.photo.errors}}
                <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product photo:</label>
                {{ form.photo }}
            </p>
</form>
```

Settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
```

views.py

```
def ProductsAll(request):
    products = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
    context = {'products': products}
    return render_to_response('productsall.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def SpecificProduct(request, productslug):
    product = Product.objects.get(slug = productslug)
    context = {'product': product}
    return render_to_response('specificproduct.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form definition in the html template.

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/addproduct/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p>
            {{form.photo.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product photo:</label>
            {{ form.photo }}
        </p>
        
        </p><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Comment: def ProductsAll(request):
    products = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
    context = {'products': products}
    return render_to_response('productsall.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))


def SpecificProduct(request, productslug):
    product = Product.objects.get(slug = productslug)
    context = {'product': product}
    return render_to_response('specificproduct.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

Comment: @wadadaaa : when asked to post your code, please either edit your question or post a link to somewhere we can see it **correctly formatted**. Unformatted code is unreadable at beast, and just **plain useless** when it's Python code. Also: "not work" is about the worst possible description of a problem.

Comment: @wadadaaa Is that the full views.py? You are not instanciating the Addproduct form in any of those views. So please provide (by editing your original post) the code of the view, that handles adding the products.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/
2. Check you are using `method="POST"` in `form` tag.
3. Check you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `form` tag.
4. Check that django has permission to write into `upload_to` dir (use admin to upload files).
5. Check your form class initialized via uploaded files object not post data only: `MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`.